# DataBase-Finding total scores

Tags: mysql, database

I've `15` levels, and each level consists of `2 rounds`. Now I've to find the total score by finding the `max score` the user earned in `round1 and round2` and calculate it. Likewise the same method up to how many levels he played. And, finally, the total result by calculating scores from all levels.

Can anyone please help me to find the total score using MySQL..!

***I tried this code:***

```
    SELECT *, (classifica_score + MAX2) AS TOTAL FROM(

    SELECT IFNULL( MAX(XX1.classifica_score), 0) AS classifica_score, XX1.classifica_level, XX1.classifica_round, XX1.fb_id,
    (SELECT IFNULL( MAX(TC1.classifica_score), 0) FROM tab_classifica AS TC1 WHERE TC1.classifica_round = 2 AND TC1.fb_id = XX1.fb_id) AS MAX2
      FROM tab_classifica AS XX1 WHERE XX1.classifica_round=1 
    GROUP BY XX1.classifica_level, XX1.classifica_round, XX1.fb_id

UNION ALL 

SELECT IFNULL( MAX(XX2.classifica_score),0) AS classifica_score, XX2.classifica_level, XX2.classifica_round, XX2.fb_id,
(SELECT IFNULL( MAX(TC2.classifica_score),0) FROM tab_classifica AS TC2 WHERE TC2.classifica_round = 1 AND TC2.fb_id = XX2.fb_id ) AS MAX1
  FROM tab_classifica AS XX2 WHERE XX2.classifica_round=2
GROUP BY XX2.classifica_level, XX2.classifica_round, XX2.fb_id


 ) AS TAB
```

my Db structure is as follows

```
classifica_id----- fb_id---classifica_nome----classifica_level----classifica_round---classifica_score
```

Comment: You might want to show your database design, otherwise people will be guessing.

Comment: any fiddle or schema+ data please!

Comment: sample date + expected resultset + what have you tried so far?

Comment: @BhupeshC ok,i've added the structure and the query which i've tried